# Android ListView scroll conflicts/challenge item touch event

Tags: android, listview, scroll, touch, mpandroidchart

I have a list view where every item is a MPAndroidChart. The problem is that on the chart i set some gestures but when i try to perform these the list view intercept the gesture and perform the scroll.
Now i want to maintain the scroll of the list view but i want to perform the gesture on chart, how this is possible?

Also disable the scroll is useless because the list view anyway intercept the touch event and sto to perform the gesture on chart.

So what i want to do is to stop the list view to intercept the chart gesture but maintain the scroll of the list view

Class of the list view

```
public class ListViewMultiChartActivity extends DemoBase {

public static Button check_button, close_button;
public static LineChartItem chart;
public static ScatterChartItem chart2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview_chart);

    check_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    close_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    check_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    close_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayList<ChartItem> list = new ArrayList<ChartItem>();

    list.add(new LineChartItem(generateDataLine(0), getApplicationContext()));
    list.add(new ScatterChartItem(generateDataScatter(1), getApplicationContext()));
    ChartDataAdapter cda = new ChartDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
    lv.setAdapter(cda);

    chart = (LineChartItem) list.get(0);
    chart2 = (ScatterChartItem) list.get(1);

    check_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chart.mChart.end_selection || chart2.mChart.end_selection) {
                Highlight[] high;
                if (chart.mChart.end_selection) {
                    high = chart.mChart.getHighlighted();
                } else {
                    high = chart2.mChart.getHighlighted();
                }
                ArrayList<Entry> position;
                ArrayList<Entry> position2;
                LineDataSet d;
                ScatterDataSet d2;
                int i;
                int j = 0;
                int size = chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetCount();
                while (j < size) {
                    i = 0;
                    position = new ArrayList<>();
                    position2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    while (i < high.length) {
                        int k = 0;
                        while (k < chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).getEntryCount()) {
                            if (high[i].getX() == chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).getEntryForIndex(k).getX() && j == high[i].getDataSetIndex()) {
                                position.add(chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).getEntryForIndex(k));
                                position2.add(chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).getEntryForIndex(k));
                            }
                            k++;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (position.size() != 0) {
                        d = new LineDataSet(position, "Data" + j);
                        d.setLineWidth(2.5f);
                        d.setCircleRadius(4f);
                        int color = mColors[j % mColors.length];
                        d.setColor(color);
                        d.setCircleColor(color);
                        chart.mChart.getData().addDataSet(d);
                        d2 = new ScatterDataSet(position2, "Data" + j);
                        d2.setColor(color);
                        chart2.mChart.getData().addDataSet(d2);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                i = 0;
                while (i < size) {
                    chart.mChart.getData().removeDataSet(0);
                    chart2.mChart.getData().removeDataSet(0);
                    i++;
                }

                Highlight[] highvoid = new Highlight[0];
                chart.mChart.highlightValues(highvoid);
                chart2.mChart.highlightValues(highvoid);
                chart.mChart.invalidate();
                chart2.mChart.invalidate();
                check_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                close_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    close_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (chart.mChart.end_selection || chart2.mChart.end_selection) {
                Highlight[] high;
                if (chart.mChart.end_selection) {
                    high = chart.mChart.getHighlighted();
                } else {
                    high = chart2.mChart.getHighlighted();
                }
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;
                while (i < high.length) {
                    j = 0;
                    while (j < chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetCount()) {
                        int k = 0;
                        while (k < chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).getEntryCount()) {
                            if (high[i].getX() == chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).getEntryForIndex(k).getX() && j == high[i].getDataSetIndex()) {
                                chart.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).removeEntry(k);
                                chart2.mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(j).removeEntry(k);
                            }
                            k++;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                Highlight[] highvoid = new Highlight[0];
                chart.mChart.highlightValues(highvoid);
                chart2.mChart.highlightValues(highvoid);
                chart.mChart.invalidate();
                chart2.mChart.invalidate();
                check_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                close_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}


/**
 * adapter that supports 3 different item types
 */
private class ChartDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChartItem> {

    public ChartDataAdapter(Context context, List<ChartItem> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getItem(position).getView(position, convertView, getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // return the views type
        return getItem(position).getItemType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3; // we have 3 different item-types
    }
}

/**
 * generates a random ChartData object with just one DataSet
 *
 * @return
 */

private LineData generateDataLine(int cnt) {
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
        values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            double val = (Math.random() * 100) + 3;
            values.add(new Entry(i, (float) val));
        }
        LineDataSet d = new LineDataSet(values, "DataSet" + z);
        d.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        d.setCircleRadius(4f);

        int color = mColors[z % mColors.length];
        d.setColor(color);
        d.setCircleColor(color);
        dataSets.add(d);
    }
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    return data;
}

/**
 * generates a random ChartData object with just one DataSet
 *
 * @return
 */

private ScatterData generateDataScatter(int cnt) {

    ArrayList<IScatterDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IScatterDataSet>();
    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
        values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            double val = (Math.random() * 100) + 3;
            values.add(new Entry(i, (float) val));
        }
        ScatterDataSet d = new ScatterDataSet(values, "DataSet" + z);

        int color = mColors[z % mColors.length];
        d.setColor(color);
        dataSets.add(d);
    }
    ScatterData data = new ScatterData(dataSets);
    return data;
}

private int[] mColors = new int[]{
        ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[0],
        ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[1],
        ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[2]
};


}
```

Abstact of the item of list view

```
public abstract class ChartItem  {

protected static final int TYPE_BARCHART = 0;
protected static final int TYPE_LINECHART = 1;
protected static final int TYPE_PIECHART = 2;
protected static final int TYPE_SCATTERCHART = 3;

protected ChartData<?> mChartData;

public ChartItem(ChartData<?> cd) {
    this.mChartData = cd;      
}

public abstract int getItemType();

public abstract View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c);

}
```

Implementation of one of item of list view

```
public class ScatterChartItem extends ChartItem implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

private Typeface mTf;
public ScatterChart mChart;

public ScatterChartItem(ChartData<?> cd, Context c) {
    super(cd);

    mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
}

@Override
public int getItemType() {
    return TYPE_SCATTERCHART;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_scatterchart, null);
        holder.chart = (ScatterChart) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // apply styling
    // holder.chart.setValueTypeface(mTf);
    holder.chart.setDescription("");
    holder.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    XAxis xAxis = holder.chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);

    YAxis leftAxis = holder.chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(5, false);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    YAxis rightAxis = holder.chart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(5, false);
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    // set data
    holder.chart.setData((ScatterData) mChartData);


    // do not forget to refresh the chart
    // holder.chart.invalidate();
    holder.chart.animateX(750);
    holder.chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    mChart=holder.chart;
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {

}

@Override
public void onMultipleValueSelected() {
    if (mChart.end_selection) {
        Highlight[] high= mChart.getHighlighted();
        ListViewMultiChartActivity.chart.mChart.highlightValues(high);
        ListViewMultiChartActivity.check_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ListViewMultiChartActivity.close_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        ListViewMultiChartActivity.check_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ListViewMultiChartActivity.close_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ScatterChart chart;
}
}
```

I use the MPAndroidChart, [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/a3c1fe6bbf7d48b79b42b3a447f946af850d86f0/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/BarLineChartTouchListener.java) there is the class where i set the gesture of the chart

Comment: Can you show some of your code, it's hard to help without understanding how you have created the list.

Comment: I add code on question

Comment: have a look here at a similar issue -- by the looks of it you need to set a chart  touch listener to the chart https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2211

Comment: Thanks you i resolve the problem with your link!

Comment: @Tasos good spotting ! you can turn your comment into an answer if you like.